# TfLiteGpuDelegate Invoke: Delegate should run on the same thread where it was initialized

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I'm working on the [tensorflow lite object detection](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview) example.
The app runs in CPU at startup.
I want do run tflite using GPU from start. However whenever I start the app with the GPU option set, the app crashes with the above mentioned error.

The error message however seems to be misleading: If I build in a delay of 10 s before running the inference starts, everything is working fine. This is a hint that the GPU-based classifier is set up asynchronously in another thread.

Is there a way to wait and check until the `TfLiteGpuDelegate` is up and running before starting the classification?

I'll try to come up with a minimal working example, but the code is quite involved.